# ITunesConnect: 3rd person transactions?

Tags: objective-c, paypal, xcode5, in-app-purchase, square

I'm making a utility application for a photographer. He is going to (obviously) be taking pictures, but wants to charge people at an event for a handful of digital images emailed or shared on social media. In this situation i would have to use Paypal or Square SDKs and not in app purchasing because he is going to compose the transaction and not the customer buying the pictures. Sort of like a mini POS system. He can't pay himself with another's credentials - so it would have to be a 3rd party solution. right? Is this against Apple's guidelines?

Am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to support in-person / face to face (swipe) credit card or keyed in credit card payments, check out the PayPal Here SDKs for iOS and Android which are now available on the PayPal Developer site:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/pph-sdk-overview/

There is also a version for Windows 8.1+ in Beta, available upon request. You can email DL-PayPal-Here-SDK@ebay.com for help with any of these.